# Find all $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$, $x,y,z>1$ such that satisfy $x\mid yz+1$, $y\mid xz+1$, and $z\mid xy+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find all $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$, $x,y,z>1$ such that satisfy $$\begin{cases}x\mid yz+1\\y\mid xz+1\\z\mid xy+1\end{cases}$$

I've found out easily that $$\begin{cases}x\nmid yz\\y\nmid xz\\z\nmid xy\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases}x\nmid y\\x\nmid z\\y\nmid x\\y\nmid z\\z\nmid x\\z\nmid y\end{cases}$$
I can't find a way to continue from here, so I'd like to get some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Much stronger than what you have, $\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(x,z)=\gcd(y,z)=1$.

Comment: If prime $p$ were to divide both $x$ and $y$, then it would also divide $yz$.  Hence, $p|yz$ and $p|yz+1$, so $\gcd(yz,yz+1)\neq 1$.  This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only solutions are permutations of $(2,3,7)$:

Assume $x \mid yz+1$, $y \mid xz+1$, $z \mid xy+1$. We have $(x,y)= (y,z) = (z,x) = 1$. Let $x< y< z$. Then as $x$,$y$ and $z$ divide $xy+xz+yz+1$ we have $$xyz \mid xy+xz+yz+1 < 3yz.$$
By $1<x$ we conclude $x= 2$. But then $y \mid (2z+1)$ and $z \mid (2y+1)$ leading to $$yz \mid 2(y+z)+1 <4z$$ from which we conclude $y=3$ using $x<y$. Finally $z \mid xy+1 = 7$ and indeed $(2,3,7)$ is a solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but how do we know that $xy+xz+yz+1 < 3yz$?

Comment: @mathh By assumption $x<y<z$. Therefore $xz< yz$ and $xy<yz$. This implies $xz \leq yz-1$. All in all $xy+xz+yz+1 \leq xy+yz+yz < yz+yz+yz = 3yz$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot about the assumption.

Comment: How does $1<x$ show that $x=2$? Nevermind, I understand it now.

Comment: @mathh By $xyz | xy+xz+yz+1 <3yz$ we know that $xyz < 3yz$. Thus $x<3$. But $1<x$ by the restriction in the problem description, and thus $x=2$. I admit that I omitted some details in the proof, I am sorry for that.

Comment: Why is it true that $2(y+z)+1 <4z$? I can see that $2(y+z)+1 <2(z+z)+1=4z+1$, but can't see why $2(y+z)+1 <4z$.

Comment: @mathh Good question, but you know more about $y,z$: By $y<z$ we have $y \leq z-1$. This is why $2(y+z)+1 \leq 2(z-1+z)+1 = 4z-1<4z$.

Comment: what this (2,3,7) solution has to do with the (2,3,7)-triangle group [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(2,3,7)_triangle_group ]?

Comment: @janmarqz So is it just a plain coincidence that the solution to this problem is your given triangle group?

Comment: Hehehe, maybe some hyperbolic geometry mystery connected with this sets on ${\Bbb{N}}^3$

Comment: @janmarqz I am sorry, I don't know about the $(2,3,7)$-triangle group. I suspect it's the law of small numbers at work.

Comment: check the first of them [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_triangle#Triangles_for_the_hyperbolic_plane ]